# Is there a class in Android like java.awt.Robot?

Tags: java, android, awt

I'm searching for a class in Android which does the same as java.awt.Robot

java.awt.Robot is able to emulate pressing and releasing keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent of `Robot`. Apps cannot control other apps, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

For testing, you can "emulate pressing and releasing keys" through any number of test frameworks, such as the standard Android JUnit test cases, uianimator, and monkeyrunner.